# Salesforce JPA Provider

Tags: java

I'd like to know if there's a JPA Provider for Salesforce. I've seen that `java-sdk` has it but it's no longer maintained https://github.com/forcedotcom/java-sdk

The end goal is to use **hibernate** to persist data in Salesforce